# how to use dust js partials

Tags: html, dust.js

The partials were used in the this way but I was getting output as undefined. Created two template files parent and child that inherits from parent.

parent.tl:

```
            <div><span><label>{+title}New{/title}</label></div>
```

child.tl:

```
            {>"parent"/}
            {<title}
        {#t}
            <p>NEW {title1} For the Child</p>
        {/t}    
        {/title}
```

I compiled those templates using dustr and included as .js in my HTML.

```
            <script src="https://raw.github.com/akdubya/dustjs/master/dist/dust-full-0.3.0.min.js"></script>
            <script src="parent.js"></script>
            <script src="child_template.js"></script>
            <div id="new"></div>
            <script>
            var r=document.getElementById("new");
            dust.render("demo", {t:{"title1":"Ram"}}, function(err, out) {
            r.innerHTML=out; 
            });
            </script>
```

Comment: try removing the quotes on parent key. try this: {>parent/}

Comment: I have removed the quotes. Its working when I removed the context "t" and overridden parent with <p>...</p> with no {title1}. Can you explain why context is creating a problem?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the partial was named when it was compiled. Is your child template named `demo` (or maybe `child` or `child_template` or `child_template.tl`? Is your parent template named `parent` or maybe `parent.tl`?

To debug, you can print out the `err` to the console:

```
dust.render("demo", {t:{"title1":"Ram"}}, function(err, out) {
  console.log(err);
  r.innerHTML = out;
});
```

Comment: I named the child template as "demo" and named parent template as "parent". When I replaced the context of t (i.e {#t}<p>NEW {title1} For the Child</p>{/t} ) with "<p>New For the Child</p>" ,its working fine. Can you clarify why the context setting is a problem in case of partials?